Detect where the user folders are located, C: or D: partition
I'm writing a .bat code that copies a .lnk file to the Desktop, it is meant to be used locally in my company, but my problem is that, some computers we have, have only the disk C: and others we move the folders (desktop, documents, ...) to D:\Users\User\ creating this difference of configuraion, is there a way that I can know if the computer has this change and then redirect the .lnk file to the right desktop?
I tried using %USERPROFILE% but it only returned C:\Users\User even if the primary files were located in D:\Users\User, and I can't check this by checking if the folder Desktop exists in C: or D:, because in some computers it exists in both (it happens because some apps send shortcuts to the Desktop), even though only one is shown as the principal user screen. Is there some variable windows has that detect this change?
Obs: the user folders are moved one by one by changing the first letter in the local tab of the properties of the folder.

FOR /f "tokens=2* delims= " %%G IN ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Desktop"') DO CALL SET "desktop=%%H"

Found an answer, when I run it, I receive D:\Users\User\Desktop, and then I moved it again to C: and received C:\Users\User\Desktop
powershell -Command "& {$path = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders').Desktop; $path}"


Why do you use PowerShell in a batch file processed by the Windows Command Processor? PowerShell is the much more powerful successor of the Windows Command Processor. There can be written a PowerShell script instead of a batch file on using PowerShell cmdlets. Why do you not reference where you found the answer? PS: A batch file solution with full explanation can be read in path of user desktop in batch files.

Although this detects/prints a location, If you are submitting an answer which does not fulfil the question tags, the least you could have done was to include the code to actually copy the intended shortcut file there too.
